# Why "Connection:" header should be removed by proxies?

Tags: http, proxy, connection

I want to write a http proxy server (in Delphi 6, with Synapse library) and I don't understand why ["Connection:" header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.10) should be removed by proxies. If that header is removed, the next server my proxy connects to, will not know what type of connection my proxy wants.

Let's say that Client1 sends a request to MyProxy with "Connection: Close" header included. MyProxy remove that header and forward the request to Server1. Now, the Server1 will think MyProxy wants a persistent connection (default in http/1.1), which is wrong.

What is the logic of this ? Em I missing something ?

Answer (score 2):

The connection options are per-connection. Each sender must set the Connection header field consistent with the connection it is using. In your case, the proxy might keep the connection to the origin server open, while your client will close the one to the proxy.

See also http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p1-messaging-26.html#header.connection, which is going to obsolete RFC 2616 very soon.